# XML Encryption/Decryption in Separate Files

Tags: xml, vb.net, cryptography, rijndael

I need to encrypt an XML file, send it to another location and decrypt it there. As you can see from the codes below, I am using the same key but it won't work (for now im simply using two local files).

The error I get is as follows:

> Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

on this line in Decrypt.aspx: *Dim xReader As XmlTextReader*

I am thinking it might be at the actual encryption stage causing errors e.g., file not saving correctly.

**Encrypt.aspx**

```
 Dim rijnAlg As RijndaelManaged
 rijnAlg = RijndaelManaged.Create()

 rijnAlg.Key = {118, 123, 23, 17, 161, 152, 35, 68, 126, 213, 16, 115, 68, 217, 58, 108, 56, 218, 5, 78, 28, 128, 113, 208, 61, 56, 10, 87, 187, 162, 233, 38}
 rijnAlg.IV = {33, 241, 14, 16, 103, 18, 14, 248, 4, 54, 18, 5, 60, 76, 16, 191}
 Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform
 encryptor = rijnAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijnAlg.Key, rijnAlg.IV)

 Dim wStream As FileStream
 wStream = File.Open("C:\test.xml", FileMode.Create)

 Dim cStream As CryptoStream
 cStream = New CryptoStream(wStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

 Dim sWriter As StreamWriter
 sWriter = New StreamWriter(cStream)

 XMLDoc.Save(sWriter)

 'Clear memory'
 wStream.Flush()
 wStream.Close()
```

**Decrypt.aspx**

```
 Dim rijnAlg As RijndaelManaged
 rijnAlg = RijndaelManaged.Create()

 rijnAlg.Key = {118, 123, 23, 17, 161, 152, 35, 68, 126, 213, 16, 115, 68, 217, 58, 108, 56, 218, 5, 78, 28, 128, 113, 208, 61, 56, 10, 87, 187, 162, 233, 38}
 rijnAlg.IV = {33, 241, 14, 16, 103, 18, 14, 248, 4, 54, 18, 5, 60, 76, 16, 191}
 Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform
 decryptor = rijnAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijnAlg.Key, rijnAlg.IV)

 Response.Write(rijnAlg.Key)
 Response.Write(rijnAlg.IV)

 Dim rStream As FileStream
 rStream = File.OpenRead("C:\test.xml")

 Dim cStream As CryptoStream
 cStream = New CryptoStream(rStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)

 Dim xReader As XmlTextReader
 xReader = New XmlTextReader(cStream)

 Dim xDoc As XDocument
 xDoc = XDocument.Load(xReader)

 xDoc.Save("C:\test.xml")
```

And for the sake of possible interest, here is the XML creation code I am using:

```
Dim XMLDoc As XDocument
    XMLDoc = New XDocument(
        New XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        New XElement("user",
            New XElement("details",
                New XElement("firstname", Firstname.Text),
                New XElement("surname", Lastname.Text)
            )
        )
    )

 XMLDoc.Save("C:\test.xml")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big thanks to Jon Skeet who pointed out the best conclusion to my issues. The final code (and improvements):

**Encrypt.aspx**

```
Using ra As RijnDaelManaged = RijndaelManaged.Create()

    ra.Key = {118, 123, 23, 17, 161, 152, 35, 68, 126, 213, 16, 115, 68, 217, 58, 108, 56, 218, 5, 78, 28, 128, 113, 208, 61, 56, 10, 87, 187, 162, 233, 38}
    ra.IV = {33, 241, 14, 16, 103, 18, 14, 248, 4, 54, 18, 5, 60, 76, 16, 191}

    encrypt = ra.CreateEncryptor(ra.Key, ra.IV)

    Using ws As FileStream = File.Open("C:\test1.xml", FileMode.Create)

        Using cs As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(ws, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

            XMLDoc.Save(cs)

        End Using

    End Using

End Using
```

**Decrypt.aspx**

```
Using ra As RijndaelManaged = RijndaelManaged.Create()

    ra.Key = {118, 123, 23, 17, 161, 152, 35, 68, 126, 213, 16, 115, 68, 217, 58, 108, 56, 218, 5, 78, 28, 128, 113, 208, 61, 56, 10, 87, 187, 162, 233, 38}
    ra.IV = {33, 241, 14, 16, 103, 18, 14, 248, 4, 54, 18, 5, 60, 76, 16, 191}

    decrypt = ra.CreateDecryptor(ra.Key, ra.IV)

    Using rs As FileStream = File.OpenRead("C:\test1.xml")

        Using cs As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(rs, decrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read)

            Using xr As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(cs)

                xDoc = XDocument.Load(xr)
                xDoc.Save("C:\test2.xml")

            End Using

        End Using

    End Using

End Using
```

Answer (score 2):

You're only closing/flushing the `FileStream`, not the `CryptoStream` or the `StreamWriter`. That doesn't give the `CryptoStream` a chance to flush its final block.

Personally I would use `Using` statements for all of them, at which point everything will be closed automatically, and I suspect you'll find it works fine. That also means your resources will be released if there's an exception - at the moment, you're not closing anything if the write fails, for example.

I would *also* not bother with the `StreamWriter` - just save directly to the `CryptoStream` instead. Otherwise you've got both the XML *and* the `StreamWriter` trying to control the encoding used.

Comment: It wouldn't let me close the other streams though. I'll try the Using method and let you know how I go. Thankyou.

Comment: @user718341: What do you mean it "wouldn't let you"? My guess is that you tried closing them in the wrong order, and they tried to flush to a closed FileStream...

Comment: "wouldnt let me" = got errors. Nope, I changed the order - I just assumed it meant that closing the last one used divvied down to the rest of them.

Comment: @user718341: "got errors" is just as vague as "wouldn't let me". What errors? Compile time, or execution time? And yes, if you genuinely closed the *last* one (`sWriter`) it would be okay. But you're closing the *first* one (`wStream`).

Comment: Ok the flushing and the closing worked. Thanks a tonne mate. I will also look into the Using statements and rectifying the amount of streams.